# Bootstrap button groups next to each other

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am displaying these 2 button groups in a modal window. How can I get them to display next to each other? (regardless of screen size)

```css
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */

.form-group input[type="radio"] {
    display: none;
}

.form-group input[type="radio"] + .btn-group > label span {
    width: 20px;
}

.form-group input[type="radio"] + .btn-group > label span:first-child {
    display: none;
}
.form-group input[type="radio"] + .btn-group > label span:last-child {
    display: inline-block;   
}

.form-group input[type="radio"]:checked + .btn-group > label span:first-child {
    display: inline-block;
}
.form-group input[type="radio"]:checked + .btn-group > label span:last-child {
    display: none;   
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="form-group">
    <input type="radio" class="radio-app-status" name="fancy-checkbox-danger" id="votingStatusDenied" autocomplete="off" value="denied">
    <div class="btn-group btn-voter-status btn-disabled">
        <label for="votingStatusDenied" class="btn btn-danger">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
            <span>&nbsp;</span>
        </label>
        <label for="votingStatusDenied" class="btn btn-default active votingStatusDeniedLabel">
            Deny
        </label>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <input type="radio" class="radio-app-status" name="fancy-checkbox-danger" id="votingStatusApproved" autocomplete="off" value="approved">
    <div class="btn-group btn-voter-status  btn-disabled">
        <label for="votingStatusApproved" class="btn btn-primary">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
            <span>&nbsp;</span>
        </label>
        <label for="votingStatusApproved" class="btn btn-default active votingStatusApprovedLabel">
            Approve
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead to create two form-group you may use only one:

```css
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */

.form-group input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

.form-group input[type="radio"] + .btn-group > label span {
  width: 20px;
}

.form-group input[type="radio"] + .btn-group > label span:first-child {
  display: none;
}
.form-group input[type="radio"] + .btn-group > label span:last-child {
  display: inline-block;
}

.form-group input[type="radio"]:checked + .btn-group > label span:first-child {
  display: inline-block;
}
.form-group input[type="radio"]:checked + .btn-group > label span:last-child {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
    <input type="radio" class="radio-app-status" name="fancy-checkbox-danger" id="votingStatusDenied" autocomplete="off" value="denied">
    <div class="btn-group btn-voter-status btn-disabled">
        <label for="votingStatusDenied" class="btn btn-danger">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
            <span>&nbsp;</span>
        </label>
        <label for="votingStatusDenied" class="btn btn-default active votingStatusDeniedLabel">
            Deny
        </label>
    </div>
    <input type="radio" class="radio-app-status" name="fancy-checkbox-danger" id="votingStatusApproved" autocomplete="off" value="approved">
    <div class="btn-group btn-voter-status  btn-disabled">
        <label for="votingStatusApproved" class="btn btn-primary">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
            <span>&nbsp;</span>
        </label>
        <label for="votingStatusApproved" class="btn btn-default active votingStatusApprovedLabel">
            Approve
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Another approach can be based on overriding the form-group display from block to inline:

```css
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */

.form-group input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

.form-group input[type="radio"] + .btn-group > label span {
  width: 20px;
}

.form-group input[type="radio"] + .btn-group > label span:first-child {
  display: none;
}
.form-group input[type="radio"] + .btn-group > label span:last-child {
  display: inline-block;
}

.form-group input[type="radio"]:checked + .btn-group > label span:first-child {
  display: inline-block;
}
.form-group input[type="radio"]:checked + .btn-group > label span:last-child {
  display: none;
}

.form-group {
  display: inline; !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
    <input type="radio" class="radio-app-status" name="fancy-checkbox-danger" id="votingStatusDenied" autocomplete="off" value="denied">
    <div class="btn-group btn-voter-status btn-disabled">
        <label for="votingStatusDenied" class="btn btn-danger">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
            <span>&nbsp;</span>
        </label>
        <label for="votingStatusDenied" class="btn btn-default active votingStatusDeniedLabel">
            Deny
        </label>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <input type="radio" class="radio-app-status" name="fancy-checkbox-danger" id="votingStatusApproved" autocomplete="off" value="approved">
    <div class="btn-group btn-voter-status  btn-disabled">
        <label for="votingStatusApproved" class="btn btn-primary">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
            <span>&nbsp;</span>
        </label>
        <label for="votingStatusApproved" class="btn btn-default active votingStatusApprovedLabel">
            Approve
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Another way to solve this is to enclose your form-group in a form-inline:

```css
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */

.form-group input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

.form-group input[type="radio"] + .btn-group > label span {
  width: 20px;
}

.form-group input[type="radio"] + .btn-group > label span:first-child {
  display: none;
}

.form-group input[type="radio"] + .btn-group > label span:last-child {
  display: inline-block;
}

.form-group input[type="radio"]:checked + .btn-group > label span:first-child {
  display: inline-block;
}

.form-group input[type="radio"]:checked + .btn-group > label span:last-child {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group ">
        <input type="radio" class="radio-app-status" name="fancy-checkbox-danger" id="votingStatusDenied"
               autocomplete="off" value="denied">

        <div class="btn-group btn-voter-status btn-disabled">
            <label for="votingStatusDenied" class="btn btn-danger">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
                <span>&nbsp;</span>
            </label>
            <label for="votingStatusDenied" class="btn btn-default active votingStatusDeniedLabel">
                Deny
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="radio" class="radio-app-status" name="fancy-checkbox-danger" id="votingStatusApproved"
               autocomplete="off" value="approved">

        <div class="btn-group btn-voter-status  btn-disabled">
            <label for="votingStatusApproved" class="btn btn-primary">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
                <span>&nbsp;</span>
            </label>
            <label for="votingStatusApproved" class="btn btn-default active votingStatusApprovedLabel">
                Approve
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add pull-left class to the form-group wrapper